# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: circleCat.name

Tags: python, sqlite

I get the following error when I run my code and I don't know why:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 27, in <module>
  File "python", line 25, in members_of_circles
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: circleCat.name
```

the code :

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect(":memrory:")
cur = con.cursor()
def creat_tables () :
    cur.execute("CREATE table circleCat (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, 
description TEXT)")
cur.execute("CREATE table members( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, level 
TEXT, crcl TEXT)")


def add_a_member(name, level, crcl):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO members (name, level, crcl) VALUES (?, ?, ?)" ,
(name, level, crcl));

def add_a_circle(name, description):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO circleCat (name, description) VALUES (?, ?)" ,
(name, description));

creat_tables ()

add_a_circle("Gaming", "for Gaming")

add_a_member("hossam", "beginner", "Gaming")

def members_of_circles():
  cur.execute("SELECT name FROM members WHERE members.crcl = 
circleCat.name")

members_of_circles()
```

Comment: Don't post links to code. The question itself should contain a [mcve]. Links may die, making this post useless. Please use proper [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) as well.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Done the required changes

Answer (score 1):

Your select query is wrong. Try this:

```
def members_of_circles():
    cur.execute("SELECT m.name FROM members m, circleCat c WHERE m.crcl = c.name")
```